# Interactable Image

Tags: java, swing, graphics, click, mouse

I already have a program that uses this picture, but how would I go about programming it so that a user could click on each individual blue square and receive a response? 
I have already tried splitting the image into individual images but I wasn't sure how to make it clickable.

Here's the image:
[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [aviationexplorer.com](http://www.aviationexplorer.com/airline_aircraft_seat_maps/delta_airlines_aircraft_seating_maps/d767300.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't tell us what your GUI library is, but if it's Swing, then the answer is simple: use a `MouseListener`. The details of the implementation will of course depend on the structure of your program.

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to add that, but yes, it's Swing. If I use a MouseListener, would I be able to make the image interactable without splitting it? Much thanks.

Comment: @nichi: yes, you could make it function without splitting the image. You would need to somehow translate the location of the click to the seat location. [tag:swing] tag added to your question.